# Scipy.nbinom vs Negative Binomial Distribution formula

Tags: python, scipy

**The provided question:**

Show using the formula for the negative binomial distribution that the probability Brian kicks his
fourth successful field goal on the sixth attempt is 0.164.

The probability of a single success is p = 0.8, the number of successes is k = 4, and the number of
necessary attempts under this scenario is n = 6.

**What I have understood:**

This should be the formula:

[image]

(From the [open intro book](https://github.com/OpenIntroStat/openintro-statistics) on page 160)

Meaning this should be the solution:
[image]

Which I can verify here:

```
>>> from math import comb
>>> comb(5,3)*(pow(0.8,4))*(pow(0.2,2))
0.16384000000000007
```

However, when I try to solve this using [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html) I get a very different answer

Given 6 attempts, 4 success, with the probability of success equal to 0.8

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(6,4,0.8)
0.002202009599999998
```

And if I try to do it the opposite way as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534730/how-to-interpret-scipys-negative-binomial-distribution).

Given 6 attempts, 2 failures, with the probability of failure equal to 0.2

```
>>> scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(6,2,0.2)
0.07340032
```

**Can someone point out the error of my interpretation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I see now the issue.

The scipy `nbinom.pmf` function should be read as:

```
scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(num_failures, num_successes, prob_of_success)
```

Where `num_failures + num_successes = total_cases`

So in my case, the args should have been:

Given 6 attempts, 4 success, with the probability of success equal to 0.8

```
>>>> scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(2,4,0.8)
0.16383999999999996
```

I still wonder why scipy has chosen this format...

Comment: *"I still wonder why scipy has chosen this format..."* Take a look at the comment in the sidebar on the right in the wikipedia article [Negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).  There are several common conventions for the parameters of the negative binomial distribution.  There is no single universally accepted parameterization that is *the* negative binomial distribution.