# Using Poisson-Gamma Distribution in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy

Having a Poisson Distribution, I would like to modify it and use the [Poisson-Gamma Distribution](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuzione_Poisson-Gamma) (unfortunately it seems that the link in English does not exist on Wikipedia), a probability distribution associated with a Poissonian random variable, Poiss(λ), in which the parameter λ is not constant but varies as a Gamma random variable; a Poisson mixture in which the parameter λ has a Gamma distribution.

How can I apply `Poisson-Gamma Distribution` to my `from_1_to_3`? (in scipy, numpy or other)

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

mu_X = 1.7

one = poisson.pmf(1, mu_X) 
two = poisson.pmf(2, mu_X) 
three = poisson.pmf(3, mu_X) 

from_1_to_3 = one + two + three
```

**UPDATE**
In a comment, they pointed out to me that, perhaps, the Poisson-Gamma Distribution would actually be a `Negative binomial distribution` with Gamma-Poisson mixture ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture)). If this is the case (i don't know if this is the case, i'm not sure), does this mean that the number of failures and successes also come into play and that therefore the answer would be this Stackoverflow answer [Scipy.nbinom vs Negative Binomial Distribution formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784876/scipy-nbinom-vs-negative-binomial-distribution-formula) ?

I hope someone can help me. Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: I think you're looking for [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture) and also see [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html)

Comment: @SurajShourie I do not know. I'm not very good with scipy and numpy. I started using them very recently. Could you show me the answer please? If you need help, I will be happy to accept your answer

Comment: Even though this is programming related, you may have more luck over on the [math.se] site instead, just because there doesn't really seem to be a "poisson-gamma distrubtion" in the English speaking world, so the first step would almost certainly be to find out how to express this in terms of functions that you can look up APIs for.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  You are right, but Suraj Shourie's comment seems to be right. The link he sent me "seems" to contain what I'm looking for, but it's called something else, it's called scipy.stats.nbinom. I'm not sure about Suraj Shourie's comment though, so I'm still waiting for a comment from him. Thanks also for your comment

Comment: @SurajShourie do you mean this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784876/scipy-nbinom-vs-negative-binomial-distribution-formula

Answer (score 0):

The *pmf* of a Poisson-Gamma distribution is obtained by integrating the *pmf* of a Poisson distribution with respect to its mean λ over the Gamma distribution, that is:

```
Pr(Poisson-Gamma = k) = integral from 0 to infinity Pr(Poisson(λ)=k) f(λ) dλ
```

where `f` is the *pdf* of the Gamma distribution.

If the Gamma distribution has shape parameter `a` and rate parameter `b`, the Poisson-Gamma distribution coincides with the negative binomial distribution with parameters `a` and `b/(1+b)`.

```py
import scipy.stats as stats 
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

# parameters of the Gamma distribution
shape = 10
rate = 2

# the probability that Poisson-Gamma = 3 is the integral of the probability that 
# Poisson(lambda) = 3 with lambda = the pdf of the Gamma distribution
def integrand(x):
    return stats.poisson.pmf(3, x) * stats.gamma.pdf(x, a = shape, scale = 1/rate)
pg3 = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.inf)
# 0.14130135486974726

# this is also the probability that Negative Binomial = 3 with parameters shape and rate/(1+rate)
stats.nbinom.pmf(3, shape, rate/(1+rate))
# 0.14130135486974693
```

Answer (score 0):

The `P(X = x| a, b, nu)` can be implemented directly

```py
import scipy.special
def poisson_gamma(x, a, b, nu):
  g = scipy.special.gamma(a+x) / (
        scipy.special.gamma(a) * scipy.special.gamma(x+1))
  return g * (b / (b + nu))**a * (nu / (b + nu))**x
```

In some cases expressions involving powers or the gamma function may grow a lot, if you want to compute beyond the limits of a double precision number, you could use the `gammaln` instead.

```py
import scipy.special
def poisson_gamma(x, a, b, nu):
  g = scipy.special.gammaln(a+x) - (
      scipy.special.gammaln(a) + scipy.special.gammaln(x+1))
  return np.exp(g + a * np.log(b / (b + nu)) + x * np.log(nu / (b + nu)))
```